# macOS - cannot rm without sudo

Tags: macos, mac, sudo, rm, macos-sierra

Brand new owner of a Mac, getting to know the machine.

I have stumbled upon an issue that is quite bothersome - I cannot use rm without sudo. Indeed anytime I write an rm command, the result is the following:

```
rm: illegal option -- I
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
   unlink file
```

whereas if I sudo the command it carries on successfully.

Extra information:

- macOS Sierra v.10.12.6
- The files all have access permissions of 777 and belong to the user 'staff'.
- `staff` is not a user-made group/user. Expectation is that is a base user/group provided by the os.

So the question is, how can I make it so that I do not need to sudo anytime I want to modify these files? (And by extension what is this 'staff' user?)

Comment: You don't need write access to a file in order to delete it: you need write access to its parent directory. Note that `sudo` operates in a different environment from the `bash` shell it is called from. It looks as though you have an alias or function which is redefining `rm` by adding extra parameters: use `type -a rm` to find all possible interpretations. Also, try `$(which rm) ...` instead of `rm ...`, to make sure you are using the proper executable (this is normally `/bin/rm`, but I have a feeling it might be different on Macs).

Comment: I'd worryabout the specific folder / file that you're trying to work in.  In an ordinary directory that the current user owns when working on an ordinary file that the current user owns, you should be able to deleted the files without trouble.

Comment: @AFH Great find! I transferred my .bash_aliases from linux and I had an error tolerance alias for rm => `rm -I` listed at the bottom of the file. Removing the line did clear up the issue! If you want you can copy your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as the proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message it looks as though you have an alias or function which is redefining `rm` by adding extra parameters, since `sudo` operates in a different environment from the shell it is called from, and does not generally import the alias and function definitions from the shell's initialisation scripts.

This command shows all possible interpretations of the `rm` command:

```
type -a rm
```

Also, within the shell you can use `$(which rm) ...` instead of `rm ...` in order to make sure you are using the proper executable, as the external `which` program doesn't know about the alias and function definitions that the internal `type` command checks. A command with a directory component always goes to the file system to find it, thereby bypassing aliases and functions.

Note that you don't need write access to a file in order to delete it: what you need is write access to its parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the comments to your question, unless your user owns the file, you'll more than likely not be able to erase the object without superuser permissions.

`Staff` is MacOS's System group. Modifying files owned by this group would be potentially dangerous, though you most likely know what you're doing in your use-case.

As for the `-I` directive, that's not in MacOS's `rm` command; you'll need to use `-i`, unless it has a similar replacement.

To skip sudo, you could add an rm alias in your .bashrc (`rm='sudo rm -i'`) and add yourself to MacOS's Sudoers file with `sudo visudo`, then appending `YOUR_USERNAME_HERE  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL` for full sudo access to all commands, or `YOUR_USERNAME_HERE  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/rm` to restrict full access to the rm command only.

**Note:** MacOS's rm command may not be located in /bin/rm. I've not used it recently, but assume it's located there from prior knowlege.

Comment: Your answer, coupled with AFH made me realize that I had an alias setup for rm that included `-I` as a default parameter. Good catch!